# how to find multiple of a number using goto sql statement?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, goto

> Write a PL/SQL block to display the multiples of a Given Number
>   without including multiples of 10 for a given range (Start Value and
>   End Value), **using GOTO.**

This is my try, but I couldn't place the `goto` statement in correct place:

```
 declare
start_value number;  end_value number; n number;
result;
begin
start_value:=&start_value;
end_value:=&end_value;
n :=&n;
for x in start_value..end_value loop
<<calc>>
if((x mod n)=0 and  (x mod 10)!=0) then 
dbms_output.put_line(x);
end if;
goto calc;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Are you getting an infinite loop, or does it fail before you get to that point?

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is a really bad assignment. Teaching you to use GOTO's is like teaching a naval architect to build ships without watertight bulkheads - it's Just Wrong. (*sigh*) But, oh well...

```
DECLARE
  start_value NUMBER;
  end_value NUMBER;
  n NUMBER;
BEGIN
  start_value := &start_value;
  end_value := &end_value;
  n := &n;

  FOR x IN start_value..end_value LOOP
    IF MOD(x, 10) = 0 THEN
      GOTO skip_calc;
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n * x);

    <<skip_calc>>
    NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The way this would normally be written is:

```
DECLARE
  start_value NUMBER;
  end_value NUMBER;
  n NUMBER;
BEGIN
  start_value := &start_value;
  end_value := &end_value;
  n := &n;

  FOR x IN start_value..end_value LOOP
    IF MOD(x, 10) <> 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n * x);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Shorter and easier to read.

Comment: why it is stupid?! sorry but that what i got ,, but thank you ,, your answer was helpful , thank you ^^

Comment: A university/college/on-line course which teaches you to use GOTOs is not doing you any favors because they are not considered good practice. [Dijkstra's article on the negative impact of GOTOs on programming](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) was published 47 years ago, and it's as valid today as it was in 1968. I suggest you turn this assignment in and then forget about the GOTO statement. Best of luck.